# java.sql.SQLException: IO Exception : The Network adapter could not establish the connection?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

Hi I am trying to connect with Oracle 11g database using ojdbc14 jar on eclipse kepler with java 8 on windows 7 os. But when I am running the code I am getting the following error. Here is my and the errors accordingly.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JDBCExample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter your databse details");
       System.out.println("user name");
       String uName = sc.next();
       System.out.println("password");
       String pWord = sc.next();
       try {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Connection conn = null;
       try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");
        // jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:xe
       } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       if (conn != null) {
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to DB");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect to DB");
       }
   }
}
```

And the Errors are as follows.
`java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:23)`

Comment: Is oracle installed and running on your machine?

Comment: Also, is the Oracle TNS listener configured and running? your JDBC URL points to localhost so we assume you have all this running on your local machine.

Comment: Yeah all these are running my machine I am not able to understand why these errors are @SlipperySeal.

Comment: The exception is saying that this port is not open on localhost. Can you connect using a JDBC based database tool?  Like DBVisualizer etc.

Comment: is  telnet localhost 1521 command working?

Comment: telnet is not recognized error showing on command prompt @ravindra

Comment: I am sorry to say @SlipperySeal that I am first timer I don't have idea how to use DBVisualizer tool. If you don't mind share some information on this please.

Comment: If you are using windows7, this command from commapnd prompt installs telnet : pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"  . (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Should I have grant permissions to connect jdbc

Comment: yeah I installed telnet client on my system

Comment: its working @ravindra

Comment: Can you connect with SQL client from your machine with same jdbc url and user name and password?

Comment: how to connect to jdbc. I tried from telnet its not connecting. It shows connection failed

Comment: @ravindra I can access the sql database from telnet . I did troubleshoot its working normally.

Comment: Try this command from command prompt: sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost:1521/xe

Comment: yes I am connected to database now. I can access sql now. Then what is the problem with java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From our conversation, you are able to telnet & connect to database from command prompt. After going through jdbcurl, I have found the error.

**localhost:1521/xe** should be **localhost:1521:xe** if xe is SID for your database.

Change this code from

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe", "scott", "tiger");
```

To

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "scott", "tiger");
```

Have a look at this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)

Comment: Its showing  java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call error

Comment: Can you post code snippet and line number? Is it the same line?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html for sample reference. is xe is SID of your database?

Comment: I have already above same code no changes in the code. errors are as follows  
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
Failed to connect to DB
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:22)

Comment: Thanks @ravindra I got it. Program executed successfully. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Start the oracle listener service from services.msc

Answer (score -4):

You are missing import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: on the stack trace it's clear that `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is there and it's used.